# bash - monitor chown (user and group) changes of folder / inotify or audit or smth. else

Tags: audit, opensuse, inotify, chown, pulseaudio

i'm on opensuse 12.3 and the owner of my /run/user/$UID/pulse folder gets changed to root:root every now and then resulting in pulseaudio not beeing able to start:

> [autospawn] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory
>   (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied [autospawn]
>   lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock. [pulseaudio] main.c:
>   Failed to acquire autospawn lock

is there a way to monitor WHEN and WHO (user, pid, program name) changes the owner? does not seem to work with inotify, however i thought it may work with audit, but i'm unable to come up with something from the docs. or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `tripwire` or `iwatch`, but `iwatch` hasn't been updated for quite a few years.

reference:
[log who creates files in a directory, maybe using inotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666606/log-who-creates-files-in-a-directory-maybe-using-inotify)