# log who creates files in a directory, maybe using inotify

Tags: linux, inotify

In my Ubuntu box, I need to monitor which script/program/user is *creating files in a path or its sub-directories*.

The main idea being to identify a possible yet unknown security hole that is being exploited to inject malicious scripts in my system.

I think it can maybe be possible with linux's INotify? Ive tried to find such a script without luck.

Can somebody suggest me a simple script to do it?

Thanks

Comment: look at tripwire, solidcore, samhain, iwatch -- they may do what you want.  also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977890/monitor-directory-listing-for-changes

Comment: @ChuckCottrill thanks very interesting stuff. I'll try iWatch...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ChuckCotrill, I finally went with

```
nohup iwatch -r -e create,delete,close_write -t .ext /my/path > /tmp/files_changed.out &

tail -f /tmp/files_changed.out
```

Comment: It seems that `iwatch` isn't maintained anymore?